# Writing an Oracle function to get the time of an event back if its not in another event

Tags: sql, oracle, function, date-arithmetic

Let me be explain what I want: There are some components which can fail due to some reasons and they have priorities. Now, what I want is that if an event occurs and its priority is low, I will pass its **start time** and **end time** to the function and see if there is some other high priority component that was there in that period of time. If there was, then there are four cases:

1. If the low priority event is in the timing of high priority event then time is 0.
2. If the end time of the event is in the high priority but start time is out side the high priority then the time outside the event.
3. If the start time of the event is in the high priority but end time is out side the high priority then the time outside the event.
4. both start and end are out means high priority comes in between the low priority event.

**Example:** Assume that every event has high priority. I am sending the start time and end time,  e.g. `12:41:01` and `12:49:01`

```
component  start time  end time  
1          12:40:01    12:50:01   result will be 0 because it's between the start & end
2          12:40:01    12:48:01   result will be 1 minute
3          12:43:01    12:50:01   result will be 2 minutes
4          12:43:01    12:44:01   result will be 7 minutes
```

I want the function to send me back the time in seconds. I have to compare it with every component all the time, and I don't know how to do it in a function only function not procedure.

Comment: Take more care in asking your question if you want help. Motor-mouthed phrasing, unpunctuated clauses, and lack of clarity won't get you very far:  ".. see if there is some other high priority component was there in that peroid of time it there was then there are four cases..."

Comment: -1 for totally unstructered text and wording

Comment: Put some CREATE TABLE plus INSERT for sample data and what you'd expect to be extracted.

Comment: Did what I could for the readability, but some of the language is still quite vague and confusing.

Comment: @user534760: In the example for component 4, did you mean ZERO minutes instead of 7?  If not, please explain the difference between components 1 and 4, and how your result of seven minutes would be computed.  Thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name lol you gave him -1 for bad wording and misspelled a word while doing it!

Comment: @orbfish: nice catch :) However the -1 was given when the question looked totally different. It was not formatted at all and had no punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following table definition

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT_OCCURRENCE
  (COMPONENT        NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
   PRIORITY         VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL
     CHECK(PRIORITY IN ('HIGH', 'MEDIUM', 'LOW')),
   START_TIME       DATE NOT NULL,
   END_TIME         DATE NOT NULL);
```

with the following data

```
INSERT INTO EVENT_OCCURRENCE (COMPONENT, PRIORITY, START_TIME, END_TIME)
  VALUES (1, 'HIGH', TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '0 12:40:01' DAY TO SECOND, TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '0 12:50:01' DAY TO SECOND);

INSERT INTO EVENT_OCCURRENCE (COMPONENT, PRIORITY, START_TIME, END_TIME)
  VALUES (2, 'HIGH', TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '0 12:45:01' DAY TO SECOND, TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '0 12:48:01' DAY TO SECOND);

INSERT INTO EVENT_OCCURRENCE (COMPONENT, PRIORITY, START_TIME, END_TIME)
  VALUES (3, 'HIGH', TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '0 12:39:01' DAY TO SECOND, TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '0 12:46:01' DAY TO SECOND);

INSERT INTO EVENT_OCCURRENCE (COMPONENT, PRIORITY, START_TIME, END_TIME)
  VALUES (4, 'HIGH', TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '0 12:38:01' DAY TO SECOND, TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '0 12:55:01' DAY TO SECOND);
```

the following procedure will NOT give the results you asked for, but given that your explanation was a bit lacking in detail I think this is the best you can hope for.  It should give you something to start from to get what you think you want:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRINT_INTERSECTING_OCCURRENCES(dtEvent_start IN DATE,
                                                           dtEvent_end IN DATE) IS
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('dtEvent_start=' || TO_CHAR(dtEvent_start, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ||
                       '   dtEvent_end=' || TO_CHAR(dtEvent_end, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));

  FOR aRow IN (SELECT E.*,
                      CASE
                        WHEN dtEvent_start >= E.START_TIME 
                             AND dtEvent_end <= E.END_TIME 
                        THEN
                          0
                        WHEN dtEvent_start <  E.START_TIME
                            AND dtEvent_end BETWEEN E.START_TIME AND E.END_TIME 
                        THEN
                          (E.START_TIME - dtEvent_start) * (24 * 60 * 60)
                        WHEN dtEvent_start BETWEEN E.START_TIME AND E.END_TIME 
                             AND dtEvent_end > E.END_TIME 
                       THEN
                          (dtEvent_end - E.END_TIME) * (24 * 60 * 60)
                    WHEN dtEvent_start >  E.END_TIME
                        OR dtEvent_end < E.START_TIME  
                    THEN
                         (dtEvent_end - dtEvent_start) * (24 * 60 * 60)
                    ELSE
                          ((E.START_TIME - dtEvent_start) * (24 * 60 * 60))
                             + ((dtEvent_end - E.END_TIME) * (24 * 60 * 60))
                      END AS TIME_DIFF
                 FROM EVENT_OCCURRENCE E
                 WHERE E.PRIORITY = 'HIGH')
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COMPONENT=' || aRow.COMPONENT ||
                         '  PRIORITY=' || aRow.PRIORITY ||
                         '  START_TIME=' || TO_CHAR(aRow.START_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ||
                         '  END_TIME=' || TO_CHAR(aRow.END_TIME, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') ||
                         '  TIME_DIFF=' || aRow.TIME_DIFF);
  END LOOP;
END PRINT_INTERSECTING_OCCURRENCES;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: +1 - this is basically what I would have coded.  I added a branch to the CASE statement to handle the situation when the passed date range lies wholly outside the record's range.

Answer (score 0):

The description doesn't seem to make sense, but I think this is what you might be looking for (assuming start_time_in and end_time_in are the names of your input variables).

```
select component, ((start_time - least(start_time, start_time_in)) + (greatest(end_time, end_time_in) - end_time)) * 24*60*60 seconds_outside_window   
from table
```